# Loop antenna $E$ and $H$ modes without approximations as to the distance or wavelength

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, antennas

In Jackson's 9.14 we calculate the expressions for $E$ and $H$ of a loop antenna with current $I=I_0\cos(\omega t)$ in the $x-y$ plane **in the radiation zone**, where we approximate the distances to be large so:

$$\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{'}|}\approx\frac{1}{\vec{r}}$$

$$|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{'}|\approx \vec{r}-\vec{r}.\vec{r}^{'}$$

But what if we want to derive an expression that is valid for lower modes of the quadrupole radiation in **all distances** without approximation? How we should approach the integral with $\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{'}|}$ in the denominator?

$$\vec{A}(\vec{x})=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int J(\vec{r}')\frac{\exp(ik|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}d\vec{r}'$$

Comment: What you need to look for is the *near field* expression for the radiation.  This is quite complicated because of back-action effects etc.  There are expressions in EEng textbooks on antenna theory but I recall reading the modelling is not so great.  This type of calculation cannot be done exactly and must be done term by term.

Comment: incidentally you have a number of typos in your question.  One cannot divide by a vector so $1/\vec r$ does not make sense and should be $1/\vert \vec r \vert$.  Likewise $\vert \vec r-\vec r’\vert$ is a scalar so you should have $\vert \vec r\vert$ on the right hand side.  Finally, your $\vec A$ is really a phasor and should be indicated as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion_(potential)) of the inverse distance:

$$\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}=
\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{4\pi}{2\ell +1}\frac{r_<^\ell}{r_>^{\ell+1}}
\sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell}Y_{\ell m}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell m}(\theta',\phi')$$
where

- $r_<$ is the smaller one of $r$ and $r'$,
- $r_>$ is the bigger one of $r$ and $r'$,
- and $Y_{\ell m}$ are the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).

If $r_< \ll r_>$, then it is sufficient to take only the first few
terms (with lowest $\ell$).

---

The expansion for
$\frac{\exp(ik|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}$
(which, apart from a factor $4\pi$, is actually the Green's function of the Helmholtz wave equation)
is more difficult in the radial factors:

$$\frac{\exp(ik|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}=
4\pi ik \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty j_\ell(kr_<)h_\ell^{(1)}{(kr_>)}
\sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell}Y_{\ell m}^*(\theta,\phi)Y_{\ell m}(\theta',\phi')
$$
where

- $j_\ell$ are the [spherical Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn,_yn),
- and $h_\ell^{(1)}$ are the [spherical Hankel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Hankel_functions:_h(1)n,_h(2)n) of the first kind.

Comment: Thanks, and what about the |r-r'| term in the exponential?

Comment: @Ummagumma Can you please add the relevant formulas into your question? I don't have Jackson's book available.

Comment: Done, I added the formula for vector potential from which E and B can be derived